# How to create a data frame from another data frame, filter rows and select specific columns all at the same time?

Tags: pandas

I have one data frame (old_df) and I want create a new data frame (new_df) to select specific columns from that df (variable1, variable2, variable3) and also filter these selected columns (where variable1 = 2016).

I know how to do all of this on separate lines/in spaghetti code, but I am trying to improve my coding by chaining things together and doing it on one line more often.
This is what I have done in the past:

```
new_df = old_df[['variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3']] #select cols i want
new_df = new_df[(new_df['variable1'] = 2016)] #filter where variable1=2016
```

I found this link which tells me how to do it, but it is not working for me when I try it
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html:

```
adult_names = titanic.loc[titanic["Age"] > 35, "Name"] #example from link
new_df = old_df.loc[old_df["variable1"]=2016, "variable2","variable3"] #my attempt
```

when I tried this, I got the following error: SyntaxError:Keyword can't be an expression

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need `==` (equality comparison operator) not `=` (assignment operator). So `(new_df['variable1'] == 2016)`

Comment: Also then loc takes a list of columns `new_df = old_df.loc[old_df["variable1"]==2016, ["variable2","variable3"]]`

Comment: @HenryEcker that worked! thank you so much